# Get orders with free items

Tags: commerce

I have a pricing rule to do some items free.
User can purchase only 3 items per month.

Question is how to programmatically get count of free items purchased by user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do something vaguely similar the other day and the only way I could find was to go into the db tables directly to grab the data. The problem is you need to join the line item and orders tables (for the order status), which you can't do with (for example) an `EntityFieldQuery`.

I think you'd be looking for a query simliar to:

```
SELECT SUM(li.quantity)
FROM {commerce_order} o 
INNER JOIN commerce_line_item li ON li.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE o.status = :status
AND li.line_item_label = :sku
AND order.uid = :uid
```

But it'll probably need some tweaking for your needs (to get results for orders created between certain dates for example).

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I think it is not that I want.I analyzed the `commerce_order` and `commerce_line_item` tables, and I can't see line_item price. I think line_items price should be saved with price including all taxes and discounts..

Comment: That's not how it works I'm afraid. The price is a field attached to the line item entity, if you want that information you'll need to select the line item ids in the above query, load the commerce_line_item entities, then extra the prices from there

Comment: Your query will return line_items counts of every order with specified status, sku and uid. And I want to know at least how to get count of line_items in specified order with price of 0.

Comment: Thanks! It's sadly I cant't to get this info with one query..

Comment: You probably could, but it would take a fair few joins to and from field tables which has its own set of problems :)

Comment: But as I can see it is the best way to solve my problem, isn't it? :)

Comment: I just don't know what kind of joins should be)

Comment: "Easiest/quickest"...yes. "Best"...no. The most robust way is to use the API as it takes care of language/revision issues. Talking you through the necessary JOINS is going to be a bit tricky on here I'm afraid

Comment: Thanks. I understood. Little to clarify: The "Best" way is to get all line_items of user orders (ex. for last month) and for each to call API function to get its price?

Comment: Just my opinion but yeah, that would be the safest way to do things

Comment: Thank you very much! (little dissapointed though)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by making the rule for payment to be above $0. It was difficult getting to the answer because they don't explain the steps, but here's my steps if you want to accomplish this:

> Go to Store>Configuration>Payment Methods and "edit" your Payment method, in my store I had to edit Paypal WPS.
>   Add a condition for the payment under "Conditions" and select "Price Comparison" . The "Operator" I selected was '>=' and I had to select $1 under "Second Price" because it didn't want to take $0 . 
>   And save your rule...then it should work although this rule is in effect catered for any products that are cheaper than $1

Answer (score 0):

You may check the following function:

```
/**
 * Count number of user purchased free products. 
 */
function foo_count_free_products($uid = NULL, $type = 'trial') {
  // Initialize the variables.
  empty($uid) && $uid = $GLOBALS['user']->uid; // If empty, set to currently logged user id.

  $orders = commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('status' => 'completed', 'uid' => $uid)) + commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('status' => 'invoiced', 'uid' => $uid));
  $product_ids = array();
  foreach ($orders as $order) {
    foreach (entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order)->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
      if (in_array($line_item_wrapper->type->value(), commerce_product_line_item_types())) {
        $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->type->value() == $trial &&
          $product_ids[] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->raw();
      }
    }

  }
  return count($product_ids);
}
```

Where 'trial' is the type of your free product, if you're using special product type for it. Otherwise, you can count all the products with zero price. You can modify this function to use with the rules.

---

Or you can use the direct SQL query, some suggestion:

```
  $result = db_query("
    SELECT
      O.order_id,
      O.created AS order_created,
      O.status AS order_status,
      (O.status NOT IN ('checkout_complete', 'pending', 'completed', 'invoiced')) AS order_in_cart,
      CP.commerce_product_product_id AS product_id,
      P.sku,
      P.`type`,
      P.title,
      SEP.commerce_subscription_end_period_interval AS length_interval,
      SEP.commerce_subscription_end_period_period AS length_period,
      CAST(O.data AS char(4096)) AS data
    FROM {commerce_order} O
    LEFT JOIN {commerce_line_item} LI ON LI.order_id = O.order_id
    LEFT JOIN {field_data_commerce_product} CP ON CP.entity_type = 'commerce_line_item' AND CP.entity_id = LI.line_item_id
    LEFT JOIN {commerce_product} P ON P.product_id = CP.commerce_product_product_id
    LEFT JOIN {field_data_commerce_subscription_end_period} SEP ON SEP.entity_type = 'commerce_product' AND SEP.entity_id = P.product_id
    WHERE O.uid = :uid AND (P.`type` IN (:subscription_types))
      AND (:search_in_cart OR O.status IN ('checkout_complete', 'pending', 'completed', 'invoiced'))
      AND product_id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY order_created ASC, O.order_id ASC
  ", array(
    ':uid' => $uid,
    ':subscription_types' => array('foo'),
    ':search_in_cart' => ($flags & FOO_WEBSTORE_GET_USER_PRODUCTS_CART) ? TRUE : FALSE,
  ))
  ->fetchAll();
```